# How to run this typescript code and create an observer function based on this example:

Tags: typescript

I got this exercise but I am unable to run it locally with ts-node.

I got a typing error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
this.result = a + b;

```
'use strict';

import { WriteStream, createWriteStream } from "fs";
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString: string = '';
let inputLines: string[] = [];
let currentLine: number = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (inputStdin: string): void {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function (): void {
    inputLines = inputString.split('\n');
    inputString = '';

    main();
});

function readLine(): string {
    return inputLines[currentLine++];
}

class Observe {
    name: string;
    args: any;
    result: number;
    getLastCall(): string {
        return `${this.name} was called with arguments ${this.args["0"]}, ${this.args["1"]} and returned ${this.result}\n`;
    }
}

const observeObj: Observe = new Observe();

const add: Function = (function () {
    var called: number = 0;
    return function add(a: number, b: number): number {
        if (called === 0) {
            called++;
            this.result = a + b;
        }
        return called;
    }
})();

const power: Function = (function () {
    var called: number = 0;
    return function power(a: number, b: number): number {
        if (called === 0) {
            this.result = a ** b;
            called++;
        }
        return called;
    }
})();

/*
 * Complete the 'observer' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a FUNCTION.
 */

function observer(func: Function): Function {
    
}

function main() {
    const ws: WriteStream = createWriteStream(process.env['OUTPUT_PATH']);

    const input = readLine().trim().split(' ');

    const x: number = parseInt(input[0]);
    const y: number = parseInt(input[1]);

    let observePower: Function = observer(power);
    observePower(x, y);

    try {
        power(1, 1);
    } catch (err) {
        ws.write("Please use the already defined functions.\n");
        ws.end();
        return;
    }

    ws.write(observeObj.getLastCall());

    let observeAdd: Function = observer(add);
    observeAdd(x, y);

    try {
        add(1, 1);
    } catch (err) {
        ws.write("Please use the already defined functions.\n");
        ws.end();
        return;
    }

    ws.write(observeObj.getLastCall());

    ws.end();
}
```

I need to complete the observer function to log the function name, arguments and result but I am unable to run it locally using ts-node.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] which demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs (*reproducible*), without necessarily including every bit of your code (*minimal*).  The easier it is for us to get started, the more likely you'll get an answer that's useful to you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the type of `result` in the beginning part of your class, like the following:

```js
private readonly result: number // for example, you should add your own type.
```